# Python parse page with dynamic content

Tags: python, ajax, parsing

Can I parse page with dynamic content with Python?

For example, I am a wannabe investor and want to parse latest SEC filings in script and push results through Telegram API to get them on the phone as soon as they appear.

So I can parse https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/entityName=TSLA for latest hype stock TSLA, f.e. But it loads results into table by ajax after page render, so I get blank table if I do:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(sec_url).text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find(id="hits").table.tbody
rows = table.find_all('tr')
```

(rows here is empty)

Comment: Have you checked whether the data is available via one of these resources: https://www.sec.gov/sec-data-resources ? If not then take a look at [selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/) to automate access via a browser.

Comment: Thanks! Great link. I already found the solution using old Edgar listing instead of new, but anyway the question is important, I'll try Selenium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load this page using `Selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

url="https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/entityName=TSLA"
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
wd.get(url)
time.sleep(5) # sleep for a few seconds to allow loading the data

soup = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, 'lxml')
table = soup.find(id="hits").table.tbody
rows = table.find_all('tr')
```

But a better solution is to load the json directly. It appears that the site uses a `post request` on this url: https://efts.sec.gov/LATEST/search-index

```
import requests

data = '{"entityName":"TSLA","startdt":"2016-03-02","enddt":"2021-03-02"}'
response = requests.post('https://efts.sec.gov/LATEST/search-index', data=data).json()
```

You can find the data in `response["hits"]["hits"]`. Loaded in a Pandas dataframe,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.json_normalize(response["hits"]["hits"])
```

This will be the `df.head()` result:

|  | _index | _type | _id | _score | sort | _source.ciks | _source.period_ending | _source.root_form | _source.file_num | _source.display_names | _source.xsl | _source.sequence | _source.file_date | _source.biz_states | _source.sics | _source.form | _source.adsh | _source.film_num | _source.biz_locations | _source.file_type | _source.file_description | _source.inc_states | _source.items |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | edgar_file | _doc | 0001771364-21-000002:edgardoc.xml |  | [1613692800000] | ['0001771364', '0001318605'] | 2021-02-17 | 4 | ['001-34756'] | ['Kirkhorn Zachary (CIK 0001771364)', 'Tesla, Inc. (TSLA) (CIK 0001318605)'] | xslF345X03 | 1 | 2021-02-19 | ['CA'] | ['3711'] | 4 | 0001771364-21-000002 | ['21658000'] | ['', 'Palo Alto, CA'] | 4 | PRIMARY DOCUMENT | ['', 'DE'] | [] |
| 1 | edgar_file | _doc | 0001422849-21-000072:SEC13G_Filing.htm |  | [1613433600000] | ['0001318605', '0001422849'] |  | SC 13G | ['005-85943'] | ['Tesla, Inc. (TSLA) (CIK 0001318605)', 'Capital World Investors (CIK 0001422849)'] |  | 1 | 2021-02-16 | ['CA'] | ['3711'] | SC 13G/A | 0001422849-21-000072 | ['21635287'] | ['Palo Alto, CA', 'Los Angeles, CA'] | SC 13G/A | SEC SCHEDULE 13G | ['DE', 'DE'] | [] |
| 2 | edgar_file | _doc | 0001104659-21-023576:tm216465d19_sc13ga.htm |  | [1613433600000] | ['0001318605', '0001446580'] |  | SC 13G | ['005-85943'] | ['Tesla, Inc. (TSLA) (CIK 0001318605)', 'SUSQUEHANNA SECURITIES, LLC (CIK 0001446580)'] |  | 1 | 2021-02-16 | ['CA', 'PA'] | ['3711'] | SC 13G/A | 0001104659-21-023576 | ['21635713'] | ['Palo Alto, CA', 'Bala Cynwyd, PA'] | SC 13G/A | SC 13G/A | ['DE'] | [] |
| 3 | edgar_file | _doc | 0001104659-21-024148:tm215669d5_sc13g.htm |  | [1613433600000] | ['0001318605', '0001721695'] |  | SC 13G | ['005-85943'] | ['Tesla, Inc. (TSLA) (CIK 0001318605)', 'Citadel Securities GP LLC (CIK 0001721695)'] |  | 1 | 2021-02-16 | ['CA', 'IL'] | ['3711'] | SC 13G/A | 0001104659-21-024148 | ['21639215'] | ['Palo Alto, CA', 'Chicago, IL'] | SC 13G/A | SCHEDULE 13G/A | ['DE', 'DE'] | [] |
| 4 | edgar_file | _doc | 0001495158-21-000002:edgardoc.xml |  | [1613088000000] | ['0001584518', '0001318605'] | 2021-02-10 | 4 | ['001-34756'] | ['Guillen Jerome M (CIK 0001584518)', 'Tesla, Inc. (TSLA) (CIK 0001318605)'] | xslF345X03 | 1 | 2021-02-12 | ['CA'] | ['3711'] | 4 | 0001495158-21-000002 | ['21631266'] | ['', 'Palo Alto, CA'] | 4 | PRIMARY DOCUMENT | ['', 'DE'] | [] |